# how to connect windows phone emulator to local server

Tags: windows-phone-7, json.net, odoo

I Want just to know how 
How we can do to access the `OpenERP` server (on `localhost`) via a `Json` request using windows phone application (emulator)?

how to connect to a `local server = (localhost access)` because I think there is no relationship between my application and the `local server`

Comment: did you try this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: thank you Bazar for your answer,but what you can tell me advantages, because I find no relationship between my OpenERP server and use a web service, so I can use a json request and to send directly to the server and retrieve BD I for example.

I think the real problem is manifested in a network configuration, it is necessary that both (localhost / machineV the emulator) use the same network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For connect to OpenErp from Visual Studio for Windows Phone, I use XmlRcp

[http://xml-rpc.net/index.html](http://xml-rpc.net/)

It's simple use and fast developing.

Regards

Comment: you have any example , connection class or how to retrieve employees data using XMLRPC.net